# overwritten file , github gave me another codes or project that i have push before the new one i was trying to push

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, github-api

i need help with my viscode i mistakenly entered a wrong command prompt while pushing to github that result in me to lost my resent works and project which was overwritten how do i restore it back all i see in subfolder are node_modules, gitignore Readme.md please help i don't know what and how

i have try try restoring it back with what i know and what i don't know . Am expecting to see the project or my codes

Comment: What command did you enter?